# How to call C# class method using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created **Class** under **App_Code** folder there i have created method.
I need to call that class method using JavaScript from Sample.aspx file.

Class:

```
namespace ContactBook.App_Code
{
    //The function need to call...
    public class ContactBook_functionalities
    {
        public static bool MyFunction(string email, string contact)
            {
                 //Code...
            }
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function callMyFunc(email, contact)
        {
             //var x = MyFunction(string email, string contact);
        }
</script>
```

[WebMethod] is not working for Class functions.

Comment: Hi, please check my answer below. You can press the upvote (upward arrow) if you find the answer helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  don't thing you can do that because:

- ASPX is server side, whereas JavaScript is client side
- some components from a ASP site are compiled

What you can do is expose a route (if you were using MVC desing pattern) on the server that calls that function (or an Api for that mather).

Comment: In that am not using any MVC desing pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose an [HTTP handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx) in ASP.net or [Controllers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-controller-cs) / [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) in MVC for your JavaScript to have the capability of talking to the server. Simple classes are not accessible outside ASP.net Application via JavaScript.

After creating your own controller/HTTP handler, you need to send an AJAX request to the controller and it should look like this code below:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "sampleurlhere",
   type: "POST"//POST or GET,
   data: {
       id: "sample id as parameter"
   },
   success: function(e) {
    //this event fires up when response arrives.
   }
 })
```

Comment: From that am not using any MVC desing pattern, So Controller is not in my Project.

Comment: @karthikeyanmlp, you can look on the links I provided on how to use HTTP handlers in ASP.net

Comment: How can i call the Handler_function with arguments using JavaScript?

I think that the below is only way to call Handler
"http://localhost/HttpHandler/test.sample"

Comment: How can i call the Handler_function with FunctionName using JavaScript?

I think that the below is only way to call Handler
"http://localhost/HttpHandler/test.sample"

And also i have use that Class_methods from CodeBehing file.
**If am write Handler, for the same operation, I need to write twice. For Class and handler.**
That is also makes problem on future because i need to update those not a single.

**Is there no other way to use class_methods directly???**

Comment: @karthikeyanmlp, please check the code I gave you. Each property of the data object is equivalent of an argument on the handler method